# What is the iOS user preference for notifying user must restart the app correctly?

Tags: core-data, ios9, restart, application-restart

I have an app that uses sharing of CoreData in iCloud *when activated by the user*.  Upon activation, the app needs to be restarted because most of the sharing code is done in AppDelegate.  What is the accepted way of not only notifying the user to restart the app, *but making sure the app is truly restarted and not just put in the background*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no accepted way, because this is a sign of a badly designed app. Apps are not allowed to simply exit (Apple will reject the app for this). Asking the user to force-quit your app is like hanging a big, flashing "crap" sign on the app.

The fact that code is in the app delegate is no excuse. First, you can (and should) move that code **out** of the app delegate. Second, even if it's in the app delegate, any object can be disposed of and re-created. That includes the entire Core Data stack. Reinitializing Core Data and your UI is a big step but it's possible. If you need to reinitialize things, then do it.

Comment: Thanks Tom... moving the initialization code out of AppDelegate is what I'll do...